# Asynchronous javascript - how to pass parameters?

Tags: javascript, database, asynchronous, parameters

Here's a snippet for asynchronous javascript:

```
var bsa = document.createElement('script');
bsa.type = 'text/javascript';
bsa.async = true;
bsa.src = 'myfile.js';
bsa.test_var = 'HI!';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa);
```

I added the line `bsa.test_var = 'HI!';` - I've tried to pass parameters into the `myfile.js` and there print out the 'test_var', but it doesn't work.

In the `myfile.js`, I've tried to call `alert(bsa.test_var)` or just `alert(test_var)`, but neither one version didn't work.

Is there any way to pass parameters? I would like to pass parameters into the `myfile.js` and there according to the parameter load data the appropriate data from database.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to `bsa.src = 'myfile.js?key1=val&key2=val'` ?

Comment: I am pretty sure async does nothing in that code.

Comment: Your example works for me. What does alert(bsa.test_var) display?

Answer (score 2):

You do not pass parameters to scripts, you pass parameters to functions.

You will need to change your script so that it doesn't actually do anything until the functions therein are *invoked*, and pass the parameters at that point.

Your problem then becomes just one of figuring out when the script has completed loading, which can be done by adding a `.onload` handler to the `<script>` element object.

Comment: You can pass parameters to scripts - that may not be what he's intending to do but it can be done. http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: @AInitak, could you give me an example/link on how to do that?

Comment: @NicholasPickering yes, he _might_ be intending to pass CGI-style parameters to a remote server that then alters the JS source based on those values.  That's almost never the right thing to do, though.

Comment: @user984621 you need to move up a level and describe what the _goal_ is, not what the problem is with your apparently incorrect approach to that goal.  Google for "XY problem"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't pass parameters to scripts.

You can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load your scripts. You will be notified when your script is loaded, at which time you can perform initialization using the needed custom parameters. It is not required to use AMD modules, but your code will be better structured if you do.

```
require('myfile.js', function (MyModule) {
    var myModule = new MyModule(customParameter);
});
```